# Import classes In Java

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I can't manage to plug in an external resources that I need to use in my code in java using Eclipse.

perhaps someone will know what seems to be the problem.

I have a zip file, I'm clicking on the project  than press "Build path"-->  External Archives
and choose my file, than In the head of the code I write "import.....".

It says that the "The import cannot be resolved".

Is this the right way to plug in external classes?

Thanks

Comment: It seems to be the right way. Normally, the library should appear inside your project's tree in the Project Explorer (left). If you open the library, can you see the expected packages and classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Zip File is an unusual means of distributing Java Classes (it's possible, but unusual). My guess is that your Zip file contains the JARs you need, so you'd have to unpack the zip file first.

Answer (score 2):

Open the `.zip` file first and if it contains the necessary `.jar` files then extract them and add them to your project.

It might also be possible that while downloading the `.jar` file it must have been saved as `.zip`

To check this open the zip file and see if it contains a `META-INF` directory with a `MANIFEST.MF` file within it.

In such a case rename the `.zip` extension of the file to `.jar` and add it to your project