# Importing JIRA source code in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jira

I am having JIRA source code in zip file. I tried to import by using File-> Import, but still getting error and java build path. I am not sure whether it is correct way to import source code in eclipse. 
Can anyone help me to import the JIRA code in eclipse.

Following are some of the errors:

- The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.
- No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the document.
- The resource is a duplicate of jira-webhooks-plugin/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/spring.xml and was not copied to the output folder.
- ComponentManager cannot be resolved.
- The method getPluginAccessor() from the type ComponentManager is deprecated.

So I think, I am wrong in Importing source code. Can anyone guide how to import the JIRA source code.

Comment: Most probably you're just missing the java build path, right click on project, select properties, select java build path add the needed libraries which usually also come with the project's source

Comment: I added required Jar libraries, but I am getting message as "NoClassFound exception may occur during Runtime."

Comment: Still looks like it's all about configuration issue in your build system but since I don't know JIRA so can't really help you. Although I've tagged your question also with jira in order to improve your chance or being helped. Good luck and welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: Is the source just the `context` of a bugreport? try to use the `myLyn` `JIRA-Connector` to import the issue and start the task, this will load the context (open the required files.).

Comment: No, Source code is the project of JIRA.I am having JIRA project Source Code. How can I import it into eclipse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import classes In Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361558/import-classes-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The JIRA source you have is a maven project.

You should check the build.sh how it compiles itself.